# Permit Delete-Votes Sooner, Please

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, vote-to-delete, time-limit

There's really no purpose to keeping questions like this ([now deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1848914/depend-on-ur-experience-whose-better-in-programming-man-or-woman)) around for any length of time. Why should we wait two days to delete this? In two days it will slip off the radar, and out of people's mind - only to waste away on Stack Overflow.

Comment: The question got deleted.

Comment: Wonder if it was my offensive vote that put it over the edge? (BTW, @jinguy, I found it based on your tweet.)

Comment: It won't waste away for long... I just recently broke 10k and have been chowing away at the closed question list, voting to delete the old cobwebby stuff. I'm only part way through October 2008, though. ;)

Comment: @gnostradamus: I noticed that! Good work :-)

Comment: Am I the only one with a perverse desire to keep that question around, just to watch the huge flamewar?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The delay time was put there to prevent the post from being deleted so quickly that people can't re-open it.  There's no heuristic for the system that can be used to determine if a question should or should not be deleted immediately with no re-open recourse, so we can't remove the delay.

tvanfosson is right - if it's obviously bad from the beginning, then offensive and moderator flags are the best recourse.

Comment: Pollyanna, eh? About time someone here used that name. Unfortunately, you're hardly the most deserving...

Comment: I am wounded, sir!  Wounded!

Comment: Has Pippi Longstocking been used yet?

Answer (score 8):

This is now available to users with at [least 20,000 reputation jingles](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/trusted-user).

> #### What are trusted users?
>
> Trusted users are allowed to perform trusted actions, including:
>
> - Voting to delete questions immediately after they are closed (even if they are new)

Answer (score 1):

Flag as offensive.  Enough people do this and it gets automatically deleted by community.  Also flag for moderator attention.  I believe they have the power to delete right away.